# Docker: using SSH in builds with Buildkit

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile, apt

Following the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) I'm trying to pass an SSH key to my container. This is my original Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
```

and this works

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=~/github .`

However, if I try to install anything with apt:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6

RUN apt update

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
```

I get the following error:

```
[+] Building 1.8s (7/9)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 306B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental                                                                                                                                                                   1.1s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental@sha256:de85b2f3a3e8a2f7fe48e8e84a65f6fdd5cd5183afa6412fff9caa6871649c44                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [2/4] RUN apt update                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.4s
------
 > [2/4] RUN apt update:
#7 0.352
#7 0.352 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#7 0.352
#7 0.359 Reading package lists...
#7 0.375 E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
#7 0.375 E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

However, the second Dockerfile actually works if Buildkit is disabled. Any suggestions on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same issue. For me the solution was to upgrade Docker. I had this issue with `19.03.11` which my Ubuntu install was pulling in as a snap. `20.10.1` (latest as of this post) worked for me.

More info here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39106#issuecomment-752246367

edit: Unfortunately this doesn't work when the `build` is run non-interactively (for example, as a systemd-based CI agent) - at least for me.